# Why my query with union operator returns only fields from first select?

Tags: sql

I need to get all values from table and values with condition for 'not null'. 
So I make two `SELECT` statements.

```
select oa.dept_id, COUNT(oa.id) quantity, sum(oa.premium) 'sum'
from Table1 oa
    Left Join Table2 od On od.id = oa.dept_id
group by oa.dept_id

Union all

select oa1.dept_id, COUNT(oa1.id) quantity1, sum(oa1.premium) 'sum1'
from Table1 oa1
    Left Join Table2 od1 On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
where oa1.action is not null
group by oa1.dept_id
```

I expect result like this with **70 rows**:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| dept.id | quantity | sum | quantity1 | sum1 | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

I got result like this with **130 rows**:

```
----------------------------
| dept.id | quantity | sum |
----------------------------
```

Comment: How many rows does the second select statement return if you run it on its own?

Comment: how many rows returned by the 1st query, 2d query and result query?

Comment: @MattGibson, If i execute only 1 query it returns about 70 rows, if i add **union** and execute 2 query together, it returns 130 rows.

Comment: That's what UNION is meant to do. The results of both queries are collected together into a single result set (the column names of the result set will be those of the first query.) Could you perhaps describe what you *expect* to happen, and how it differs from what's actually happening?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш : your question says `with condition for 'null'` and query says `oa1.action is not null` ....am I missing something here? :\

Comment: @MattGibson, I edit my question and expectations.

Comment: @NoobEditor, You are right. I correct my question. Thanks!

Comment: @ViktorBardakov, Короче я хотел чтоб они мне выводили подряд столбцы, а запрос выводит мне сперва результат от первого запроса а потом со второго.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш : i don't mean to be rude but i think u need to study about SQL, `union` consolidates values of 2 query's and lists them, i think you need 2 different columns from 2 different tables.....either u r confused or i got requirement wrong!! :)

Comment: ....and use common language in comments.....-1 for being regional!

Comment: @Шыназ Алиш ну так и объединяй в один запрос через Join (см. мой ответ). Когда делаешь Union просто строки добавляются от второго запроса

Comment: @ViktorBardakov. Рахмет))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use join

```
    select a.dept_id, quantity, sum,quantity1,sum1
    from 
    (
      select oa.dept_id, COUNT(oa.id) quantity, sum(oa.premium) 'sum'
      from Table1 oa
          Left Join Table2 od On od.id = oa.dept_id
      group by oa.dept_id
    ) a
    join
    (
      select oa1.dept_id, COUNT(oa1.id) quantity1, sum(oa1.premium) 'sum1'
      from Table1 oa1
          Left Join Table2 od1 On od1.id = oa1.dept_id
      where oa1.action is not null
      group by oa1.dept_id
    ) b
    on a.dept_id=b.dept_id
```